# Is there a tactic in Coq to make a hypothesis from applying two hypotheses?

Tags: coq

Suppose in Coq we have the following hypotheses:

```
x, y, z: Z
H : x < y
H0 : y < z
```

and I would like to introduce also the hypothesis

```
H1 : x < z
```

which follows from `H` and `H0` using `Z.lt_trans`.
Is there a better way to do this than the following?

```
assert (H1 : x < z). 
{ apply Z.lt_trans with y.
  exact H. exact H0.  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may for instance write `specialize (Z.lt_trans  _ _ _ H H0) as H1.`

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Pierre's answer, here are two more options.

First, you can use `transitivity y` instead of having to dig through the library to discover `Z.lt_trans`:

```ml
Require Import ZArith.
Open Scope Z.

Lemma rabbit (x y z : Z) (H : x < y) (H0 : y < z) : True.
Proof.
  assert (H1 : x < z).
  { now transitivity y. }
  trivial.
Qed.
```

Second, you can use [ssreflect `have` tactic](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ssreflect-proof-language.html#coq:tacn.have) like this:

````ml
Require Import ZArith.
Open Scope Z.
From Coq Require Import ssreflect.

Lemma chicken (x y z : Z) (H : x < y) (H0 : y < z) : True.
Proof.
  have H1 : x < z by transitivity y.
  trivial.
Qed.

```
````